# For what we need python cosole in pycharm (or any IDE) if we have the editor? and vice versa

Tags: python, pycharm

Im new to pycharm and coding, and can't really understand why i need two places to write my code in.

And also in pycharm there is the run window where I can see the output of my code, but on spyder for example I see the output in the console window.

Why every thing in coding is so messy and complex?

Comment: What do you mean with "two places"? In general, you write longer programs in files (so you can save and re-run them), and shorter ad-hoc things in console views.

Comment: @AKX by two places i mean you can write codes both in the editor and the console. so from what i understand from you the console exists just to check short codes and run them without running the whole script and then add them to the 'original' code in the editor?

Comment: In a newspaper you can read the words directly on paper, but in a PDF you read it in a computer screen. You can do the same thing in both of them: read. Do you find these messy and complex? PyCharm and Spyder are just different software where you can do the same thing: code.

Comment: Coding may be "messy and complex" because different people have their own preferences. For example, a python console might be useful for some, who want to execute ad-hoc python statements when at a breakpoint. I, too, have tried different IDEs and found some are too complex for what I need to do. You might try a different IDE.

Comment: @Enzo but why the output on spyder is shown in the console but on pycharm its not? on spyder i thought the purpose of the console is to see the output, and suddenly on pycharm it does't do that, it has a run window for that, so what do we need the console for and why the output is not in the console?

Comment: PyCharm and Spyder just work differently in that sense. You can have multiple Run tabs in PyCharm for different invocations of your program, and multiple consoles for your various interactive sessions.

Comment: @Kevin thanks kevin, im sure nothing is really that messy, i just need to understand the root cause of things. and also my teachers tells me to work with pycharm so i have to.

Comment: Yes, the purpose of the console is to receive input and display output, but it can be done in a better way. PyCharm uses a console under-the-hood, but it displays to you a nice and beautiful Run window. That's one from the many differences between two. I understand why you find it "messy and complex", but I think a better definition would be just "different".

Comment: I hear you, inevitably the "root cause" is "someone found it useful so we'll throw it in there!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Python Console is used to test and debug programs


Coding is so Complex because computers are complex too, for exemple if we say a bit, the computer doesn't know that. he needs a numeric value for a bit(*exept* machine learning)

I know it's hard to get started at coding, but for example what I found good when I started was coding a game to learn many things. Maybe just look up ursina, it's an cool engine in which you could code games pretty fast and easy.

Comment: i can't just write thank you because comments must have at least 15 characters, so thanks